# Drag n Drop using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am using jQuery UI for drag n drop.

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ND17/mpu8qtss/2/)

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="" class="draggables">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input type="text" name="textinput" />
    </div>

    <div id="" class="draggables">
      <label>File Upload</label>
      <input type="file" name="fileinput" />
    </div>

    <div id="" class="draggables">
      <label>Textarea Input</label>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="textareainput" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sortable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Note that Here `draggable` and `sortable` are id of div

I am using clone for drag from  `draggable` and drop into `sortable`. now i want to when drag from `sortable` and drop into `draggable` that element destroy without any changes of `draggable` element means 3 div of `draggable` will be remain same but if `draggable` element drop in `draggable` than 3 div will not remain same

I know this is happen because i m using drop event. how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution In Droppable jQuery UI there is a method accept using that i solve this problem .

```
$(function() {

  $( "#sortable" ).droppable({
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
         ui.draggable.addClass( "droppables" ); //using this add class
     }
   });
   $('#draggable').droppable({
      accept: ".droppables",  // using this which draggable elements are accepted by the droppable.
      drop: function(event, ui) {
          ui.draggable.remove();
      }
  });

});
```

look at jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ND17/mpu8qtss/3/)